# Trying to convert one python program to exe but its not converting and showing it is in process of conversion even after 10 hours

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyinstaller

I use pyinstaller to convert python files to exe and its working fine for all but for except one new script which is working fine in jupyter and when I am trying to convert it to exe file,its not converting but showing that it is in process of conversion from .py to .exe even after i left system for one night and in morning m seeing no progress.

I am using jupyter and using pyinstaller to convert .py to .exe and its working fine for other codes but not the current one.

```py
   !pyinstaller --onefile C:\Users\new.py
```

Actual outcome:No outcome is coming only showing process that it is in process of converting py to exe.

Expectation:.exe file.

Comment: What is your code? Also, try to run your executable from the command line and put the output here.

Comment: ok will try to run from command line will post you the output.thanks.

Comment: When i tried with command line it converted py to exe but took more time and file size is 280 Mb  and m using pandas in my code to convert data from list to excel.